# How to use reduce() for extracting information from nested data in javascript ? (ES6)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am parsing JSON data and using `batdata.reduce()` I am trying to find the frequency of how the batsmen got out in cricket game. So I am using `a` as `accumulator` and `how` as `currentValue`. So I will get the frequency of different values of `how` (see in JSON data link above).

When I try to `console.log(catches)`. I get the frequency like eg: `LBW: 20, CAUGHT: 69, DNB: 14, RUNOUT: 3 ......` but in console I am also getting `undefined:60` why so ? (See screenshot)

chart.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import batdata from "./batdata";

const catches = batdata.reduce( (a,{how})  =>{
    if(!a[how]){
        a[how]=1;
    }else{
        a[how]=a[how] + 1;
    }

    return a; 

}, {});

console.log(catches);
```

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: There is a lot in batData, but I think 60 of them don't have the `how` property

Comment: @Logar There are two `how` one we can access directly by `batdata.how` and other one is `batdata.dismissal.how`. How can I find frequency of ``batdata.dismissal.how``

Comment: Indeed. If you look at your last 60 records. they only have the `how` property inside their dismissal property, not on the main record.

Comment: @Shilly In my code it counts `how` which is outside dismissal how can I find frequency of `how` which is inside `dismissal` using reduce ?

Comment: So you don't want any 'base' `how`, only dismissal hows ?

Comment: @Logar No not the base `how` because the base `how ` is not present but the `how` inside dismissal is present. How can I do that using reduce() ?

Comment: I don't know if I got you right, there is undefined dismissal hows, also. I tried to get you an answer, feedback welcome

Comment: @Logar Ok got it so `undefined` is present in both `how`. Your answer is very helpful thanks.

Comment: The exact answer indeed depends on which hows you want to add together and when. Then again, to avoid problems like this, I would make sure the batdata records always have the how property. Rule of thumb, don't code exceptions if you can fix the data at the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only dimissal hows, you can do :

```
const catches = batdata.reduce( (a,{dismissal})  =>{
    a[dismissal.how] = !a[dismissal.how] ? 1 : a[dismissal.how] + 1;
    return a;
}, {});
```

Now, if you want base how when present, and dismissal how when not present, you can do :

```
const catches = batdata.reduce( (a,{how, dismissal})  =>{
    if(typeof how === 'undefined')
        a[dismissal.how] = !a[dismissal.how] ? 1 : a[dismissal.how] + 1;
    else
        a[how] = !a[how] ? 1 : a[how] + 1
    return a; 
}, {});
```